# multiple instances of same node.js app on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, multiple-instances

Is there an option on AWS to run multiple instances of same node.js app?
I try to run multiple instances of my node.js app on my computer, and it gives me EADDRINUSE error. When I change the port number in my code, save it as new js file, then I am able to run multiple instances. But how could I set this on AWS? Does maybe AWS Elastic Beanstalk have some option to set this? I couldn't find it..

This is part of my app where I communicate with clients, that's where I change the port number:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response){
var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
if(path=="/getjson"){

    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end('_testcb(\''+string+'\')');             
    console.log(new Date() + " - response sent to client");

}

}).listen(port);
```

Or maybe you have some better solution for running multiple instances of an same node.js app? Note that multiple instances need to share an small database.

Comment: Do you want to run a single copy of your node application across multiple aws intsances?  Do you want to run multiple copies on one "server", all listening to different ports?

Comment: I'm interested in both options. Basically what I would like is application to scale according to number of clients, so wait time for clients is little as possible. I don't have much experience with AWS, so I'm interested in what is best practice for this kind of problem?

Comment: If you don't have much experience with AWS then I would recommend deploying your Node application on Elastic Beanstalk. It will allow you to easily run your app on multiple servers, and a load balancer will evenly distribute your site traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use node's cluster api. [documentation here](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)

```
            var cluster = require('cluster');
            var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

            if (cluster.isMaster) {

                    // Fork workers.
                    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
                            cluster.fork();
                    }

                    cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
                            console.log('Cluster worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
                            cluster.fork();
                    });

            } else {

                    http.createServer(function(request, response){
                    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
                    if(path=="/getjson"){

                                    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
                                    response.end('_testcb(\''+string+'\')');             
                                    console.log(new Date() + " - response sent to client");

                    }

                    }).listen(port);

            }
```

Comment: OK, this should work on any processor with multiple cores if i'm right?Basically what I would like is application to scale according to number of clients, so wait time for clients is little as possible. I don't have much experience with AWS, so I'm interested in what is best practice for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried amazon Load Balancing? more details can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/?nc1=h_ls). Load balancer can also manage auto scaling depending on trafic. See more documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_SetUpASLBApp.html).